# WKWebview is nil in swift

Tags: swift, wkwebview

I am working on wkwebview , when wkwebview object loads for first time ,it working fine. But when I use the same web view obj to load with different url for second time, web view is nil.

```
    @IBOutlet weak var webview: WKWebView!
     if var urlString = docuSignViewModel.url {
        let url = URL(string: urlString)!
            webview.load(URLRequest(url: url))
        }

          webview.navigationDelegate = self
          webview.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
```

Comment: What does "web view returns nil" mean? I don't see where the web view should return anything.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez when I use the same web view to load with different url for second time , I am getting "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" in webview.load(URLRequest(url: url)) statement

Comment: So your web view is being deallocated. Are you removing it from the view at some point?

Comment: No. I am loading the web view in Notification Center observer method. 



`@objc func showdocusign(notification: NSNotification) {
 if let url = notification.userInfo?["docusignurl"] as? String   {
      if var urlString = docuSignViewModel.url {
        let url = URL(string: urlString)!
            webview.load(URLRequest(url: url))
        }
          webview.navigationDelegate = self
          webview.allowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = true
      }
} `

Comment: You are not providing enough information to debug this issue. I would recommend that you google `IBOutlet var nil` or provide a reproducible example. If you do, add it to your question, don't post code in the comments.